# A issue about expiration of Distribution Certificate?

Tags: iphone, deployment, app-store

When I prepare to deployment my app to AppStore, I saw expiration of Distribution Certificate (below image), this mean expiration of my app (after upload to AppStore) is "Nov 19, 2012", That's right?
[image]

Comment: That means that you have to upload your app and get it approved prior to November 19th, 2012. This does however not mean that the app will be pulled from the AppStore once that certificate expires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Distribution certificate has nothing to do with the expiration of your app.  It only has to be valid on the day you upload it to iTunes Connect.  Then Apple re-codesigns the app with a different certificate.